# Result wrong Type

Tags: python

I have code which is giving me an error when it runs through a system that check code from question 1 to question 18 and cant progress to the next question see below.

if i run the code on Colab there is no error but an error when i run it on the learning platform that checks all answers. I'm a beginner and have spent hours trying to correct this with no luck any help is greatly appreciated.

QUESTION

Which speed is the highest?

Assign your answer to train_speeds. You may find the Python max() function useful, along with the .index list method:

```py
train_speeds = [64, 76, 93, 101, 84]

fastest_speed = max(train_speeds)

fastest_speed = train_speeds.index(fastest_speed)

print(fastest_speed)

3
```

Also tried this but didn't use .index method same error

```py
train_speeds = [64, 76, 93, 101, 84]

print(max(train_speeds))

101
```

This is the error I'm getting, but how do i get Expected type: str

```
Your result was in the wrong type
----------
- You returned type: int
- Expected type: str
```

Comment: Your answer is expected to be a string, you return an integer. With `value_str = str(value_int)` you can convert `value_int` into a string stored in `value_str`.

Comment: Your code is incorrect and raises an error in `fastest_speed = train_speeds.index(train_speeds)`. This should be `fastest_speed = train_speeds.index(fastest_speed)`

Comment: I expect this is an issue of not reading the question or a poorly worded question.  Is what you write the EXACT text?.  Turn your answer into a function `def func_name(): ... return xyz` that returns a string.  Use the return `str(variable)` function or return an f-string `return f"{variable}"`  then call that function  `answer = func_name()`